# Deploying Dockerized NextJs Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Throws 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am able to build and run my nextjs application locally with docker-compose, everything works fine. But when I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, I get successful deployment but when I go to the url of the environment I get 502 Bad Gateway.

I've tried many different things, multiple different templates I have found online for the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. I've been able to run locally in many different ways but none of them work on elastic beanstalk.

If anyone has any insight I would appreciate it. Also I know the 100 lines of logs is a bit much down below but I thought any guidance might help for a faster resolution.

Important files below, and also here is the full repo -> https://github.com/mphbo/logan-thomas-production

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
# COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
# RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# If using npm with a `package-lock.json` comment out above and use below instead
# AWS seems to have issues with old package-lock files, I have not included so that it is created on build
COPY package.json .
RUN npm i

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=deps /app/package-lock.json ./package-lock.json
COPY . .


# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

# RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size 
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Also here are some of the last 100 lines of the logs from my most recent build. Had to remove most for size requirements from stack overflow.

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-stdouterr.log
----------------------------------------
Attaching to current_web_1
web_1  | info  - Loaded env from /app/.env
web_1  | Listening on port 3000


----------------------------------------
/var/log/docker-events.log
----------------------------------------
2022-03-17T03:20:54.704808186Z container destroy 9dfce132adf4411cb21998b4b680a8bd6cd460d85eb5df91886b244d3f4db330 (image=sha256:e3b21b7beaf5e68b05f3baca37d7b4fbcb114ba6d21f3bc890e45cd7384b8ba7, name=quizzical_leavitt)
2022-03-17T03:20:54.721955363Z container create ba23c18a0a8d82d2c1415b17f7ddf3c789ceac4dc4b145fa407d1897441a8822 (image=sha256:4d7510d46ddf6b2f523595a76270d9b99a00751e21b69560592fea60de9c5ec8, name=modest_morse)
2022-03-17T03:20:54.811489936Z container destroy ba23c18a0a8d82d2c1415b17f7ddf3c789ceac4dc4b145fa407d1897441a8822 (image=sha256:4d7510d46ddf6b2f523595a76270d9b99a00751e21b69560592fea60de9c5ec8, name=modest_morse)
2022-03-17T03:20:54.818358483Z image tag sha256:cdc27002fa166b55f0e0f17a258e8064ed8563b92d9d541d3483f3e4c5d7a525 (name=staging_web:latest)
2022-03-17T03:20:59.655258896Z container kill 5ebaa6c044e5484217d3c86c526d16ec52060590eb7b0751dbc8ada2ffce7f54 (com.docker.compose.config-hash=bb2863a542c107f09564fc88d62b338c563b5de443e0dc4e7a788ffcd8d342ad, com.docker.compose.container-number=1, com.docker.compose.oneoff=False, com.docker.compose.project=current, com.docker.compose.project.config_files=docker-compose.yml, com.docker.compose.project.working_dir=/var/app/current, com.docker.compose.service=web, com.docker.compose.version=1.29.2, image=current_web, name=current_web_1, signal=15)
2022-03-17T03:20:59.675186211Z container die 5ebaa6c044e5484217d3c86c526d16ec52060590eb7b0751dbc8ada2ffce7f54 (com.docker.compose.config-hash=bb2863a542c107f09564fc88d62b338c563b5de443e0dc4e7a788ffcd8d342ad, com.docker.compose.container-number=1, com.docker.compose.oneoff=False, com.docker.compose.project=current, com.docker.compose.project.config_files=docker-compose.yml, com.docker.compose.project.working_dir=/var/app/current, com.docker.compose.service=web, com.docker.compose.version=1.29.2, exitCode=0, image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17T03:20:59.755111992Z network disconnect c00f61c330f9ce4f2664214e5e99f8420b224e0cfe8c24ef90d30eef70653510 (container=5ebaa6c044e5484217d3c86c526d16ec52060590eb7b0751dbc8ada2ffce7f54, name=current_default, type=bridge)
2022-03-17T03:20:59.764733369Z container stop 5ebaa6c044e5484217d3c86c526d16ec52060590eb7b0751dbc8ada2ffce7f54 (com.docker.compose.config-hash=bb2863a542c107f09564fc88d62b338c563b5de443e0dc4e7a788ffcd8d342ad, com.docker.compose.container-number=1, com.docker.compose.oneoff=False, com.docker.compose.project=current, com.docker.compose.project.config_files=docker-compose.yml, com.docker.compose.project.working_dir=/var/app/current, com.docker.compose.service=web, com.docker.compose.version=1.29.2, image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17T03:20:59.788410889Z container destroy 5ebaa6c044e5484217d3c86c526d16ec52060590eb7b0751dbc8ada2ffce7f54 (com.docker.compose.config-hash=bb2863a542c107f09564fc88d62b338c563b5de443e0dc4e7a788ffcd8d342ad, com.docker.compose.container-number=1, com.docker.compose.oneoff=False, com.docker.compose.project=current, com.docker.compose.project.config_files=docker-compose.yml, com.docker.compose.project.working_dir=/var/app/current, com.docker.compose.service=web, com.docker.compose.version=1.29.2, image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17T03:20:59.836566662Z network destroy c00f61c330f9ce4f2664214e5e99f8420b224e0cfe8c24ef90d30eef70653510 (name=current_default, 


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-docker-process.log
----------------------------------------
2022/03/16 00:56:29.964855 [INFO] Loading Manifest...
2022/03/16 00:56:29.964950 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2022/03/16 00:56:29.981151 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:080740215952:stack/awseb-e-xp7qsktpsk-stack/733824c0-a4c3-11ec-8cd3-0ebb713b3873 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1
2022/03/16 00:56:30.757661 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:080740215952:stack/awseb-e-xp7qsktpsk-stack/733824c0-a4c3-11ec-8cd3-0ebb713b3873 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-1
2022/03/16 00:56:31.224117 [INFO] Checking if docker is running...
2022/03/16 00:56:31.224134 [INFO] Fetch current app container id...
2022/03/16 00:56:31.224156 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker ps | grep 175915dc5ee7
2022/03/16 00:56:31.264646 [INFO] 175915dc5ee7   2517f92be235   "python /tmp/applicaâ€¦"   8 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   8000/tcp   focused_hypatia

2022/03/16 00:56:31.264686 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker wait  175915dc5ee7


----------------------------------------
/var/log/docker-compose-events.log
----------------------------------------
2022-03-16 04:55:49.722213 container create ccf18ec9402847bc1f635abbc26f3effae8d6d4aac609fd885fbcc72b024637a (image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-16 04:55:50.459344 container start ccf18ec9402847bc1f635abbc26f3effae8d6d4aac609fd885fbcc72b024637a (image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-16 05:28:02.520420 container create d40272c0074c0b6e1ab4859c402f73cd4d3d1ce75c8d7373eddf68f74726bfa4 (image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-16 05:28:03.240080 container start d40272c0074c0b6e1ab4859c402f73cd4d3d1ce75c8d7373eddf68f74726bfa4 (image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-16 05:43:21.269955 container create 6427b013979c0da82e636ca1022887fe7bde12977ed921f296d71f03d1b18e3d (image=current_web, maintainer=NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-16 05:43:21.909654 container start 6427b013979c0da82e636ca1022887fe7bde12977ed921f296d71f03d1b18e3d (image=current_web, maintainer=NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-16 05:43:21.943149 container die 6427b013979c0da82e636ca1022887fe7bde12977ed921f296d71f03d1b18e3d (exitCode=127, image=current_web, maintainer=NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-16 05:43:23.650946 container destroy 6427b013979c0da82e636ca1022887fe7bde12977ed921f296d71f03d1b18e3d (image=current_web, maintainer=NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17 02:05:43.050073 container create b8fbe93e240c9023b7d4351cd1b65fb4ead54206cf28fb9e7cc58b89f2457619 (image=current_web, maintainer=NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17 02:05:43.703614 container start b8fbe93e240c9023b7d4351cd1b65fb4ead54206cf28fb9e7cc58b89f2457619 (image=current_web, maintainer=NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17 03:15:25.417627 container create 5ebaa6c044e5484217d3c86c526d16ec52060590eb7b0751dbc8ada2ffce7f54 (image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17 03:15:26.022821 container start 5ebaa6c044e5484217d3c86c526d16ec52060590eb7b0751dbc8ada2ffce7f54 (image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17 03:21:01.472006 container create 9a99c07fd6c6629ff92da05bc71692075a1ac0bf7a79d25e613eacf5cb9553c7 (image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17 03:21:02.081385 container start 9a99c07fd6c6629ff92da05bc71692075a1ac0bf7a79d25e613eacf5cb9553c7 (image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17 18:03:09.231168 container create 466ad0e8612ca55ba04307739873bff518d989d60ee02ba47fbfa868586cf7a3 (image=current_web, name=current_web_1)
2022-03-17 18:03:09.812741 container start 466ad0e8612ca55ba04307739873bff518d989d60ee02ba47fbfa868586cf7a3 (image=current_web, name=current_web_1)


----------------------------------------
/var/log/docker
----------------------------------------
Mar 16 00:54:30 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:30.393689697Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
Mar 16 00:54:30 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:30.409736448Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Mar 16 00:54:30 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:30.409762244Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Mar 16 00:54:30 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:30.409794007Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Mar 16 00:54:30 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:30.409808870Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Mar 16 00:54:30 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:30.431080302Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Mar 16 00:54:30 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:30.431104184Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Mar 16 00:54:30 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:30.431124156Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Mar 16 00:54:30 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:30.431135443Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Mar 16 00:54:30 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:30.625879192Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Mar 16 00:54:31 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:31.162175982Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Mar 16 00:54:31 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:31.291890951Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Mar 16 00:54:31 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:31.578800386Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=b0f5bc3 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.7
Mar 16 00:54:31 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:31.579749223Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Mar 16 00:54:31 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:54:31.605571872Z" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Mar 16 00:56:21 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:56:21.102008961Z" level=info msg="Layer sha256:764fa8ef33a160d2a5c2bd412220c846a8a586bf966e03d6ea04f01c5524c219 cleaned up"
Mar 16 00:56:21 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T00:56:21.220730612Z" level=info msg="Layer sha256:764fa8ef33a160d2a5c2bd412220c846a8a586bf966e03d6ea04f01c5524c219 cleaned up"
Mar 16 02:01:57 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T02:01:57.345559855Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=f37efcfa2861a94bd4589834f691cd1ac44db54513a7edc6291922310cb85e28 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Mar 16 02:02:38 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T02:02:38.733711684Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=ad83de473f3447c452d68d482fe0828b521cd7029dd4952d061d5b706ffb644a module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Mar 16 02:02:45 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T02:02:45.150779851Z" level=info msg="Layer sha256:aad4e7071a27ac48a27bf0e78a7e1c06cf76968554d091929cc735a0a005c50e cleaned up"
Mar 16 02:10:26 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T02:10:26.395144645Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=d78d3b1e4bb25e89fc217ec17a39dbe32afbf5b092782c48387e20e74eb5bff4 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Mar 16 02:11:06 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T02:11:06.695819171Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=e714a6196094ad30b9bacbc56a154cadd171573ecf2ccfc003935a6bb3e173bf module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Mar 16 02:11:12 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T02:11:12.381263816Z" level=info msg="Layer sha256:aad4e7071a27ac48a27bf0e78a7e1c06cf76968554d091929cc735a0a005c50e cleaned up"
Mar 16 04:46:26 ip-172-31-4-118 docker: time="2022-03-16T04:46:26.034993236Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" 


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
2022/03/17 18:03:08.417529 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker-compose up -d
2022/03/17 18:03:09.961410 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker-compose-log.service
2022/03/17 18:03:09.970952 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2022/03/17 18:03:10.082890 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2022/03/17 18:03:10.093958 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable eb-docker-compose-log.service
2022/03/17 18:03:10.214523 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker-compose-log.service
2022/03/17 18:03:10.224477 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active eb-docker-compose-log.service
2022/03/17 18:03:10.234898 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start eb-docker-compose-log.service
2022/03/17 18:03:10.327790 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker-compose ps -q
2022/03/17 18:03:11.528797 [INFO] 466ad0e8612ca55ba04307739873bff518d989d60ee02ba47fbfa868586cf7a3

2022/03/17 18:03:11.529329 [INFO] Executing instruction: Clean up Docker
2022/03/17 18:03:11.529347 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker ps -aq
2022/03/17 18:03:11.569500 [INFO] 466ad0e8612c

2022/03/17 18:03:11.569536 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker images | sed 1d
2022/03/17 18:03:11.616081 [INFO] current_web   latest       619583f1d6ce   9 seconds ago        114MB
<none>        <none>       e571fa5f409b   10 seconds ago       360MB
<none>        <none>       329affc64c2a   About a minute ago   454MB
node          16-alpine    0e1547c0f4a4   5 weeks ago          110MB
node          lts-alpine   0e1547c0f4a4   5 weeks ago          110MB

2022/03/17 18:03:11.616128 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 0e1547c0f4a4 node:16-alpine
2022/03/17 18:03:11.616133 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 0e1547c0f4a4 node:lts-alpine
2022/03/17 18:03:11.616144 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rm `docker ps -aq`
2022/03/17 18:03:11.693698 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rmi `docker images -aq`
2022/03/17 18:03:13.198494 [INFO] Deleted: sha256:e571fa5f409bbdedd55795e0c90a17e12635069c6c6eaec33c8e0b0e46f1b57f
Deleted: sha256:f4379e9f6e5670d36350d042c308bd559add51d613914cea76c1f7ba0a69281d

2022/03/17 18:03:13.198511 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag 619583f1d6ce current_web:latest
2022/03/17 18:03:13.198534 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 619583f1d6ce current_web:latest
2022/03/17 18:03:13.258536 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag e571fa5f409b <none>:<none>
2022/03/17 18:03:13.258573 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag e571fa5f409b <none>:<none>
2022/03/17 18:03:13.260182 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag 329affc64c2a <none>:<none>
2022/03/17 18:03:13.260193 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 329affc64c2a <none>:<none>
2022/03/17 18:03:13.261564 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag 0e1547c0f4a4 node:16-alpine
2022/03/17 18:03:13.261615 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 0e1547c0f4a4 node:16-alpine
2022/03/17 18:03:13.307632 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag 0e1547c0f4a4 node:lts-alpine
2022/03/17 18:03:13.307671 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 0e1547c0f4a4 node:lts-alpine
2022/03/17 18:03:13.357160 [INFO] Executing instruction: start X-Ray
2022/03/17 18:03:13.357177 [INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
2022/03/17 18:03:13.357181 [INFO] Executing instruction: configureSqsd
2022/03/17 18:03:13.357201 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip configure sqsd daemon ...
2022/03/17 18:03:13.357206 [INFO] Executing instruction: startSqsd
2022/03/17 18:03:13.357214 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip start sqsd daemon ...
2022/03/17 18:03:13.357219 [INFO] Executing instruction: Track pids in healthd
2022/03/17 18:03:13.357223 [INFO] This is an enhanced health env...
2022/03/17 18:03:13.357237 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf aws-eb.target | cut -d= -f2
2022/03/17 18:03:13.363354 [INFO] eb-docker-compose-events.service docker.service eb-docker-compose-log.service eb-docker-events.service cfn-hup.service healthd.service

2022/03/17 18:03:13.363374 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf eb-app.target | cut -d= -f2
2022/03/17 18:03:13.369062 [INFO] 

2022/03/17 18:03:13.369625 [INFO] Executing instruction: Configure Docker Container Logging
2022/03/17 18:03:13.372466 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks
2022/03/17 18:03:13.372481 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/postdeploy/
2022/03/17 18:03:13.372495 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist
2022/03/17 18:03:13.372501 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2022/03/17 18:03:13.373123 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Engine execution has succeeded.","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment completed successfully.","timestamp":1647540193,"severity":"INFO"}]}]}

2022/03/17 18:03:13.373272 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

2022/03/17 18:03:43.354453 [INFO] Starting...
2022/03/17 18:03:43.354502 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2022/03/17 18:03:43.354542 [INFO] reading event message file
2022/03/17 18:03:43.356863 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2022/03/17 18:03:43.356974 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2022/03/17 18:03:43.480863 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:080740215952:stack/awseb-e-xp7qsktpsk-stack/733824c0-a4c3-11ec-8cd3-0ebb713b3873 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1
2022/03/17 18:03:43.811316 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:080740215952:stack/awseb-e-xp7qsktpsk-stack/733824c0-a4c3-11ec-8cd3-0ebb713b3873 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-1
2022/03/17 18:03:44.136679 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2022/03/17 18:03:44.136692 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2022/03/17 18:03:44.136697 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2022/03/17 18:03:44.137649 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2022/03/17 18:03:44.137659 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2022/03/17 18:03:44.139172 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2022/03/17 18:03:44.142190 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-stdouterr.log
2022/03/17 18:03:44.143761 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/docker-events.log
2022/03/17 18:03:44.146376 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-docker-process.log
2022/03/17 18:03:44.148615 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/docker-compose-events.log
2022/03/17 18:03:44.150308 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/docker
2022/03/17 18:03:44.152670 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-hooks.log
----------------------------------------


----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
----------------------------------------
172.31.11.179 - - [16/Mar/2022:04:43:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1438 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```

Comment: Is this a load balanced environment? Or a single instance EB environment?

Comment: Did you check target group of EC2 instance ?check EC2 health check  to any errors

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution. After hours of debugging, changing the docker file and docker-compose, and searching online for an answer a coworker explained to me that port 80 needs to be exposed... not port 3000 as I have in the docker-compose file.